# Need help making a relationship work with (2) classes

Tags: java, class, constructor, tostring, getmethod

I am trying to verify what is wrong with my class builds to make address class communicate with my warehouse class. My get() and set methods along with toString() is in question. Any help would be greatly appreciated

public class Address
{

```
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private int zip;


public Address()
{
    setStreet("");
    setCity("");
    setState("");
    setZip(0);
}


public Address(String str, String c, String sta, int z)
{

    setStreet(str);
    setCity(c);
    setState(sta);
    setZip(z);

}

public String getStreet()
(

    return street;

}

public String getCity()
{

    return city;

}

public String getState()
{

    return state;

}

public int getZip()
{

    return zip;

}

public void setStreet( String str)
{

    street = str;

}

public void setCity( String c)
{

    city = c;

}

public void setState( String sta )
{

    state = sta;

}

public void setZip( String z )
{

    zip = z;

}

public String toString()
{


    return( " Street " + street + " City " + city  +" State " + state + " Zip " + zip);

}
```

}

Must communicate with the following warehouse class:

public class Warehouse
{

```
private double squareFeetSize;
private double pricePerSquareFoot;
private int televisions;
private int computers;
private Address address;



public Warehouse()
{
    setSquareFeetSize(0.0);
    setPricePerSquareFoot(0.0);
    setTelevisions(0);
    setComputers(0);
    setAddress(new Address());

} 


public Warehouse( double s, double p, int t, int c, Address a)
{

    setSquareFeetSize(s);
    setPricePerSquareFoot(p);
    setTelevisions(t);
    setComputers(c);
    setAddress(a);


} 


public double getSquareFeetSize()
{

    return squareFeetSize;

} 


public double getPricePerSquareFoot()
{

    return pricePerSquareFoot;

}


public int getTelevisions()
{

    return televisions;

} 


public int getComputers()
{

    return computers;

} 

public Address getAddress()
{
    return address;

}


public void setSquareFeetSize( double s)
{

    squareFeetSize = s;

} 


public void setPricePerSquareFoot ( double p )
{

    pricePerSquareFoot = p;


} 

public void setTelevisions ( int t )
{

    televisions = t;

} 


public void setComputers ( int c)
{

    computers = c;

} 

public void setAddress( Address a)
{
    address = a;


}

public String toString()
{

    return (" Square Foot Size " + squareFeetSize  + " Price Per Square Foot " + 
        pricePerSquareFoot + " Televisions " + televisions + " Computers " +
        computers + " Address " + address.toString());

} 


public double calculateWarehouseCharge()
{
    double charge = 0.0;
    charge = (squareFeetSize * pricePerSquareFoot + (2.25 * televisions) + (5.50 * computers));
    return charge;

} 


public double purchaseTelevision( int quantity, double price)
{

    double cost = 0.0;
    if( quantity > televisions)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Television Quantity Unavailable");
        price = 0.0;
    }

    else
    {
        cost = price * quantity;
        televisions = televisions - quantity;

    }


    return cost;    

} 


public double purchaseComputer( int quantity, double price)
{

    double cost = 0.0;
    if( quantity > computers)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer Quantity Unavailable");
        price = 0.0;
    }

    else
    {   
        cost = price * quantity;
        computers = computers - quantity;

    }

    return cost;

}
```

}

Comment: Define: "Communicate"

Answer (score 0):

```
class Address{
    private street = "123 Lame Street";

    public getStreet(){
        return street;
    }
}

class Warehouse{
    Address address = new Address();  // create an instance; not just declare

    public void shipping(){
        shipTo(address.getStreet());  // Here's how to "communicate"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on correct way. Your code is working. Because ToString is method of Object class that you overwrite in your class. http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/api/java.lang.Object.html

Are you not getting correct result ?